# Using external variable in rspec-puppet test

Tags: ruby, rspec, puppet, rspec-puppet

Have some stuck with using variable in rspec.
Here is my params.pp

```
case $::osfamily{
  Debian: {
    $ssh_daemon = "ssh"
  }
  Redhat: {
    $ssh_daemon = "sshd"
  }
```

In an rspec test I need to use the variable $ssh_daemon like this:

```
it { should contain_service("${ssh_daemon}").with(
  :ensure => 'running',
  :enable => 'true',
)}
```

Here is my ssh.pp file

```
service { "${ssh_daemon}":
  ensure => running,
  enable => true,
}
```

How can I write this variable ($ssh_daemon) to get this test to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by mocking Facter output.

Something like:

```
context 'service on debian' do
  let(:facts) { { :osfamily => 'Debian' } }
  it { should contain_service("ssh") }
end

context 'service on redhat' do
  let(:facts) { { :osfamily => 'RedHat' } }
  it { should contain_service("sshd") }
end
```

Comment: IOW, your test needs to anticipate the variable values to prod for sensible results. Or to take another angle - your test makes sure that the variable actually *will* take the correct value.

Comment: Thanks for help, using mocking facter is the right answer and it work properly.